# load a php page which has a flash by webview and crash without error log

Tags: javascript, android, flash, webview

I have occurred a problem. In my app,I load a url(a php page) by webview. It runs fun in many devices.But in a TV device,it offen exit without any error log.Now I know it is because the php page load a swf flash.But the page show well in the browser in the Tv.My code is as follows:

```
mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.shopWebView);
mWebView.setOnKeyListener(this);
mWebView.setInitialScale(100);

WebSettings webSet = mWebView.getSettings();
webSet.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSet.setBlockNetworkImage(true);
webSet.setSupportZoom(true);
webSet.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSet.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webSet.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSet.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
//      webSet.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
    }
});

mWebView.loadUrl(URL_SHOP);
```

Who can tell me what's wrong with my code or the reason of this case?(Forgive my poor English.)

Answer (score 0):

Use WebChromeClient. That May help.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient()); 

public class MyWebClient extends WebChromeClient {

}
```

Comment: Which method should I override or  which point should I care for?

Comment: Change This mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {}) into mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebChromeClient() {})

Comment: I have solved this problem.I did like this:Before webview load url,I set the webview gone;and set webview visible in onPageFinished().Although I have solved the problem,but I don't know the exactly reason of that condition.If anyone know,please tell me.

Comment: I think Webview refreshed at onPageFinished. Anyway happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.I did like this:Before webview load url,I set the webview gone;and set webview visible in onPageFinished().Although I have solved the problem,but I don't know the exactly reason of that condition.If anyone know,please tell me.Is it because the TV's vedio memory or other things like that?